# How to pass additional parameter via |> operator in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have below code in elixir:

```
function1(param1) |> calculator()
```

the value returned from `function1` will be passed as parameter to `calculator`. What I want is to add an additional parameter to `calculator`. How can I combine it with the one returned from `function1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```elixir
function1(param1) |> calculator(param2)
```

The pipe operator passes the left hand side of the operator as the first argument to the function on the right hand side. Additional arguments to the function on the right hand side are provided inside the parentheses as usual.

Rewriting using pipes:

- `calculator(function1(param1))` → `function1(param1) |> calculator()`
- `calculator(function1(param1), param2)` → `function1(param1) |> calculator(param2)`

Here's a demo module:

```elixir
defmodule Demo do
  def make10(), do: 10
  def add(a, b), do: a + b
end
```

And an example iex session:

```elixir
iex(1)> Demo.add(1, 2)
3
iex(2)> Demo.make10()
10
iex(3)> Demo.add(Demo.make10(), 5)
15
iex(4)> Demo.make10() |> Demo.add(5)
15
```

If you want `function1` to be able to pass multiple parameters to `calculator`, that's not possible because `|>` only pipes one parameter. But you can easily solve it by wrapping all the parameters inside a tuple and passing them as one parameter. You can use pattern matching in the definition of `calculator` to extract the values from the tuple:

```elixir
defmodule Demo2 do
  def make_tuple(), do: {5, 10}
  def add({a, b}), do: a + b
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> Demo2.make_tuple()
{5, 10}
iex(2)> Demo2.add({1, 2})
3
iex(3)> Demo2.make_tuple() |> Demo2.add()
15
```